# Entering air ticket costs in a UK Visa application

Tags: visas, uk, standard-visitor-visas

In the UK visa application form they ask for your cost of the air ticket, if I'm stopping somewhere in between before coming to the UK, do I need to give a figure of the whole air fair example: home country-Italy-UK for just the basic fare from home country to the UK ?

---

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should give full details of the entire trip, because they want to know that you can reasonably afford the entire trip.  If you give them an itinerary that includes Italy, and then report the cost of the tickets as if you were *not* flying to Italy, they will see the inconsistency.  The inconsistency will then call the credibility of the application into question, likely resulting in a refusal.

Comment: Alright so basically the cost of the ticket should reflect home country-Italy-UK if I give them the itinerary that includes Italy. 
and what about the hotel ? should I include the reservation of the hotel in Italy as well ? and reflect it in the accommodation cost.

Comment: @Adil your safest course of action is to use your "additional information" statement to itemize costs for Italy and the UK separately.  Whether you should include only the UK amount or the entire amount in the application questions depends on the wording of the question itself (for example, "what is the cost of your accommodation in the UK" as opposed to "what is the cost of your accommodation for this trip").

Comment: its written "The cost of your accommodation" in the form thats it.

Comment: @Adil then pick whichever one makes the most sense to you.  As long as you clarify in your "additional information" statement, they cannot call your credibility into question.

Comment: @Adil this is a good answer, why are you not accepting it? Is something incomplete?

Comment: what if I write the total cost of accommodation in Italy + UK in that box, supply them hotel confirmation for both with the same amount and not write it in additional details?

Comment: @Adil if you do that they will look unfavorably on your application because you will have demonstrated that you did not read the guidance.

Comment: Ok then I will include it in the additional details  as suggested, thanks and sorry for a lot of questions :)

Comment: @Adil it's nothing to apologize for. This is a question and answer site, after all.  I want to be clear about the guidance comment, though: you should not submit hotel bookings with your application.

Comment: so I'll just write the cost in the box and explain in additional details, for example total cost of accommodation 400GBP and in additional details I will write hotel in italy 150GBP & in uk 250 GBP.

Comment: @phoog question updated with a screen shot, review your answer if needs be.

Comment: I submitted my online form, in the accommodation box I wrote 400GBP and in additional information I explained hotel cost in Italy 130GBP & in UK 270GBP. I hope thats fine.